# How to sum a series of numbers in bash

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, linux-mint

I run this bash code in Linux:

```
B=$(top -d 1 -b -n 9| grep $A | awk '{print $9}' | bc)
```

which A is a process name.it will set be to something like this:

```
38.7 69.1 81.0 83.3 86.9 87.3 88.3 89.3 90.2
```

i want to sum these numbers in bash.i tried:

```
B=$B+$(top -d 1 -b -n 9| grep $A | awk '{print $9}' | bc)
```

but it doesn't work correctly.
how can i get sum of these numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo 38.7 69.1 81.0 83.3 86.9 87.3 88.3 89.3 90.2 |
    tr ' ' \\n | awk '{s+=$0}END{print s}'
```

In your case, you can simply replace the awk in your pipeline with:

```
awk '{s+=$9}END{print s}'
```

Comment: i use echo $B | awk '{s+=$9}END{print s}' which B is the top command result in above but it only gives me the last number

Comment: Yes, the command you give would indeed print the last number (more precisely, the 9th number).  Try using one of the commands provided in this answer.  (eg, `echo $B | tr ' ' \\n | awk '{s+=$0}END{print s}'`)